# Unable to trigger submit in angularJS from a single button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Using `ng-submit` I have a form submission callback namely `submitFN`. Have 2 buttons:

- Fund my startup!
- Reset

My desirable output is on clicking the reset button, the input field gets 0. And on clicking "Fund my startUp" it shows an alert. How to attain this?

**Problem**:
Both the buttons are triggering the submitFN. Unable to reset.

**Code**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js">


    </script>
    <script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

      mainApp.controller('startUpController', function($scope) {
        $scope.funding = {
          startingEstimate: 0
        };

        $scope.calculate = function () {
          $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
        };

        $scope.submitFN = function () {
          window.alert('Go and find more customers.')
        }

        $scope.resetFN = function () {
            $scope.startingEstimate = 0;
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app='mainApp'>
        <form ng-submit="submitFN()" ng-controller="startUpController">
          Starting: <input type="text" ng-change="calculate()" ng-model="funding.startingEstimate"/>
          Recommended: {{funding.needed}}
          <button>Fund my startup!</button>
          <button ng-click="resetFN()">Reset</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I am entirely novice in angularJS and any help is highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
One of code I tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js">


    </script>
    <script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

      mainApp.controller('startUpController', function($scope) {
        $scope.funding = {
          startingEstimate: 0
        };

        $scope.calculate = function () {
          $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
        };

        $scope.submitFN = function () {
          window.alert('Go and find more customers.')
        }

        $scope.resetFN = function () {
            $scope.startingEstimate = 0;
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app='mainApp'>
        <form ng-submit="submitFN()" ng-controller="startUpController">
          Starting: <input type="text" ng-change="calculate()" ng-model="funding.startingEstimate"/>
          Recommended: {{funding.needed}}
          <button>Fund my startup!</button>
          <button type = "button" ng-click="resetFN()">Reset</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the button `type` is submit, so you the 2nd button also has button type `submit`. If you don't want to submit a form on that button, you should explicitly make that button type as a `button`

```
type="button"
```

Also you had mistake in resetFN code, It should be modify a value which is assigned to ng-model

```
    $scope.resetFN = function () {
        $scope.funding.startingEstimate = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @pankaj, check my code in the updated question. I tried what u said. But now clicking on the reset isnt working.

Answer (score 3):

corrected code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js">


    </script>
    <script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

      mainApp.controller('startUpController', function($scope) {
        $scope.funding = {
          startingEstimate: 0
        };

        $scope.calculate = function () {
          $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
        };

        $scope.submitFN = function () {
          window.alert('Go and find more customers.')
        }

        $scope.resetFN = function () {
            $scope.funding.startingEstimate = 0;
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app='mainApp'>
        <form ng-submit="submitFN()" ng-controller="startUpController">
          Starting: <input type="text" ng-change="calculate()" ng-model="funding.startingEstimate"/>
          Recommended: {{funding.needed}}
          <button>Fund my startup!</button>
          <button type="button" ng-click="resetFN()">Reset</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey @kukkuz can u just guide what was I missing? Ur code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You miss `funding`

```
$scope.resetFN = function () {
   $scope.funding.startingEstimate = 0;
}
```